# Effect on I2C Communication with change in Temperature (Extreme Temperatures)

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, i2c, temperature

I have a requirement to use I2C communication at extreme temperatures (-85C to 140C). I was told that the I2C Communication will not work at such extreme negative temperatures. I cannot get a satisfactory answer from google either.

The only thing that i can think about is I2C requires Pull-Up resistors and they may change with change in temperature (very little) and that change may have an impact on the communication lines. But that will not be a communication limitation but rather a hardware limitation.

How is SPI better than I2C at these temperatures ?

One explanation i was told is that the RISE time and FALL time of the signal will vary and that will effect the I2C communication (higher error rate)

Can someone please give me a logical explanation to this ? i am really not convinced.

Comment: The problem is not only about the communication line, but on the chip to do the work. Industrial temperature range are usually -40 +85 °C. Due to various factors your chip is not certificated and not tested at that extreme temperatures. You can consider dilatancy as one of main factors. You should thing to isolate your HW in a temperature controlled box to respect the allowed temperatures.

Comment: You should also consider derating of all components, for example oscillator/quartz that clock your device: it can change a lot of between -85 + 140 °C so your serial output can vary a lot not respecting the transmission parameters.

Comment: @LPs, Thank you for the quick response. So are you saying that the product is usually not tested for this range ? But is it a protocol limitation ? by what i understood from you comments. the effect should have equal impact on SPI and I2C or any other communication for that matter. Do correct me.

Comment: This question is not a software issue and should be posted on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead.  You need to observe the component temperature range limits specified in the datasheet of *all* components in your system - at those extremes many components may fail. I2C itself is not specifically "temeperature sensitive".

Comment: Yes, the impact is on the whole HW, not on protocol. BTW all HW is sold with specific temperature ranges. You can see it on the product code: a part of it declare temperature range, eg I=industrial.

Answer (score 2):

The protocol is not limited in temperature. Your problem will be to have the hardware (all components + the PCB) to work at these temperatures.
Industrial grade -40 to +125°C is something achievable.

SPI is not less limited than I2C in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that I have tested the i2C communication at -93C and -85C for almost 2 days continuously for an IC which is NOT rated below -40C.

I confirm that there was no issue in I2C communication for the past 2 days.

The long run effects i am unaware. I just wanted to add my observations.